# .done ajax giving me an error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I'm creating a contact form that sends an email using ajax and PHP.

I Seem to get an error when i run this script.

> error: Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token .

using chrome BTW.

I also have a PHP file, but i don't think that is relevant, i can add it if needed.

```
    $(function() {
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
    var formData = $(form).serialize();


    $(form).submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $(form).attr('action'),
      data: formData
    });

    .done(function(response) {
      $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
      $(formMessages).addClass('success');

      $(formMessages).text(response);

      $('#name').val('');
      $('#email').val('');
      $('#message').val('');
    })

    .fail(function(data) {
      $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
      $(formMessages).addClass('error');

      if (data.responseText !== '') {
          $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
      } else {
          $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: `});` **Remove semicolon** after `$.ajax`.

Comment: var jqxhr = $.ajax( "..." ).done(function() { alert("success"); }); this is actual syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are terminating the ajax call by putting a semicolon and after that you are calling `.done()`. The correct syntax is:

```
$.ajax( "..." )
.done(function() 
{ 
    alert("success"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon after $.ajax , from what i can tell you want to do a ajax on submit but you ajax is outside the submit event, place the code in the submit event

```
  var form = $('#ajax-contact');
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
    $(form).submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(form).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: $(form).attr('action'),
          data: formData
        })

        .done(function(response) {
          $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
          $(formMessages).addClass('success');

          $(formMessages).text(response);

          $('#name').val('');
          $('#email').val('');
          $('#message').val('');
        })

        .fail(function(data) {
          $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
          $(formMessages).addClass('error');

          if (data.responseText !== '') {
              $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
          } else {
              $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
          }
        });
```